# redirect pages in codeigniter website

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, hyperlink

I have a website http://fantastictravels.co/. I want to redirect my pages but it giving me the 404 error. my link for the page is "base_url()/Travels/search_travel" while Travels is my controller name and search_travel is the function of my controller.

My base_url in config file is "http://fantastictravels.co" and my htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

any one have any idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you name your class and filenames correct explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: This appears to have been resolved as the link now works. Although I would call the search_travel method just search so the url reads /travels/search which is nicer IMHO.